# Is there a package, method or model to Transcribe audio (voice) in R locally without calling an API

Tags: r, audio

My googling has failed me thus far, but is there an R Package or Method to transcribe audio (in my case, voice conversation mp3's) locally, without hitting a API? (I know there is many google/aws etc.. ways) but I need a on server local option.
or alternatively, is there a way to build/dev/train your own model to this?

Comment: noone? really? Please? :)